# Compiling an scss file into a css file at a specific location

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have the following folder structure:

```
|- webpack.config.js
|- src/
  |- main.js
  |- some.other.js.files
|- styles/
  |- app.scss
  |- animation.scss
  |- transition.scss
|- public/
  |- js/
    |- app.js
```

I have Webpack configured such that it takes all the css and js files and compiles them as `app.js` under `public/js`. Here is the config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.to.public.js,
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]},
  }
}
```

Now I want to create another scss file, called `static.scss`, and instead of getting it added to app.js like the others, I want it to be compiled into a stand-alone css file under `public/css`. This is so that I can link to it from some html files I have elsewhere in the repository.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract specific targeted css using  Extract Text WebPack Plugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/